# How to get uneven heights of text across columns with "multicol" package

Tags: multicol

The package `multicol` provides the `multicols` environment.  The `multicols` environment breaks non-tabular text into columns. However, it breaks the columns to that there is a (roughly) even amount of text in the columns.

In the example below, filler text is inserted into the page. It is broken into two columns of equal height, even though it did not reach the bottom of the page in the first column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}       
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[3] % filler text
\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

How do I get each column to reach the end of the page without splitting for symmetry?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  Perhaps some code or an image would help clarify.  However, the `tabularx` package has means for expanding columns out to make a table full width.

Comment: `multicols*` environment

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Fair. Fixed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Further specified.

Comment: @kando as I say `multicols*` environment does exactly what you ask.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Haha, I see. I thought you were correcting my spelling somewhere, regarding the use of `s`. Thank you.

Comment: @Mico What gives; hatred for whitespace?

Comment: @kando - I edited the title and first paragraph mainly to avoid terms, such as "asymmetrical", that are (unintentionally, of course) ambiguous. E.g., is there asymmetry in the heights or the widths of the columns? The deletion of the blank lines in the MWE was done mainly to make its appearance more compact. If you feel that the code looks better with more blank lines, please let me know and I'll undo the edits.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - You should make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package provides a `multicols*` environment that does exactly what you ask.